# Infinitely small quantities of various orders explained via a geometric illustration involving a circle ( Bouasse, Cours de mathématiques générales)

Tags: geometry, analysis, soft-question, circles, infinitesimals

In his *Cours de mathématiques générales* Bouasse illustrates the idea of infinitely small quantities of various orders via a geometric example involving a circle.

He resorts to a property of the figure ( image below) , namely :

$(1)$ $\overline {BC} \times \overline {BD} = \overline {BA}^2$

$(2)$ $\overline {AE} \times \overline {ED} = \overline {CE}^2$

My question is a basic one and  only deals with the ***explanation of the two above  properties***. In fact I have no idea of how to justify these geometric statements. Do they have any relaion with the Pythagorean theorem? ***Do these properties bare a name so that I could look by myself for further information?***

[image]

As to infinitely small quantities of various orders, his statement is as follows :

"Let's consider AB as basic  infinitely small quantity. Let's join the moving point $B$ to the fixed point $D$; and let's look for how the lines $\overline {CA}$, $\overline {CE}$, $\overline {CB}$, $\overline {AE}$ vanish ( tend to zero) , when $B$ tends toward $A$.

First, it is obvious that the arc $\overline {CA}$ and the chord $\overline {CE}$ tend to equal
$\overline {AB}$. Therefore, the magnitudes [or quantities]  $CA$ and $CE$ are first order quantities [ infinitely small quantities of first order] , since their ratio with the basic infinitely small quantity [namely $AB$] tends toward a finite limit ( which is $1$ in this particular example). "

-

Comment: Triangle ACB is similar to triangle DAB. That explains (1). Probably something like that for (2).

Comment: Yes also (2) comes from similar triangles: CED and AEC from which: $\dfrac {AE}{CR} = \dfrac {CE}{ED}$

Comment: $BC.BD=BA^2$= **power of point B with respect to the circle** (have you already heard about this concept ?)

Comment: I have found this excerpt on page 20 of this book that I have in its 1947 edition. The books by Bouasse (there are maybe ten of them, all others being in physics) have the merit to be very didactic and to contain sometimes themes that are no longer taught. But they also convey old ideas. I wouldn't recommend to use them alone but as a complementary documentation.

Comment: So, Vince, are you happy with the explanation of the properties?

Comment: I didn't add that the second relationship connects two ways to compute the power of internal point $E$ with respect to the circle. The fact that Bouasse doesn't mention the concept of power of a point with respect to a circle isn't a good point (pun intended) for him...

Comment: The concept of " power of a point" and the associated theorem whereof I found a demonstration online helped me a lot. Thanks @JeanMarie

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Perfectly happy. Thanks to you all.